# AS3 Code generation from a wsdl

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, ant, wsdl

As part of a nightly build i want to automate the generation of action script classes like Flex does but in an automated fashion.

So I'm looking for an equivalent tool to flex builder 3's Import Web Service functionality, but accesable to a Hudson nightly build using ant.

Any idea's on tools to achive this.

Comment: great question, definitely couldn't answer it with 30 seconds of googling :) http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_4.html

Answer (score 1):

Check out [WSDL2AS](http://osflash.org/wsdl2as) and also file a [feature request](http://bugs.adobe.com) with Adobe.

Comment: Okay, looks like an option. 

Only issues is that it's currently at version 0.1. Any idea how effective it is? And how bugs are dealt with.

Just signing up to adobe to get a feature request in ;)

Comment: https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-13090

This looks being the relevant feature request.